# Does the quest for beating Ore Chasm count towards the "Did it all" achievement?

Tags: achievements, borderlands-2

Title says it all and I think there is no further text required.

Comment: Why would you think it might not count? Just curious.

Comment: @JamesJiao Some quests in the game are known to glitch out for various reasons, but doing those quests from the start in someone else's game usually fixes the issue.

Comment: @Krazer Ah ok. I didn't have any issues getting this achievement. I probably bypassed these issues somehow then.

Comment: I found out today that even the quest to kill that lvl 50 loot boss counts towards it. Did all Sidequests, except this one, but did not get the achievement on Steam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Every side mission counts, hence the description of the achievement.

These are the missions you are after:

- Hyperion Slaughter: Round 1
- Hyperion Slaughter: Round 2
- Hyperion Slaughter: Round 3
- Hyperion Slaughter: Round 4
- Hyperion Slaughter: Round 5